# User settings per project in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio

Is it possible to have project settings specified per developer (as to not have it checked into source control)?

One use case, for example, is that some developers prefer to use IIS Express and others don't. Publishing could also be different.

Comment: See https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/272773/visual-studio-user-settings-per-projec

Comment: "Closed as By Design" with the last response 4 years ago :(